# Loading spinner in Vue.js from FileInput

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web-applications

I have a problem that I can't get my head around.
I am using Three.js in my web app and I want to add a loading spinner when I upload a file.
For that I created a component with the loading spinner, and display it with v-if when the file gets loaded.

Strangely enough, this does not work, even though the value "loading" is true when logged from within the function (when I log it after the file is loaded it is false again without changing it).

The code:

```
<template>
<div class="button-draw-container">
    <input id="file-input" name="button-upload" type="file" @click="importFile"/>
</div>

<div v-if="loading" id="wrapper-loader">
    <Loader/>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    components: {
        Loader
  },
  data() {
    return {
        loading: false,
  }
},
methods: {
importFile() {
        var fileInput = document.querySelector("#file-input");
        var cores = []; 
        var outline;
        fileInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
            //This is the part that's not working
            this.loading = true;
            console.log(this.loading)

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {               
                const contents = event.target.result;
                const loader = new Rhino3dmLoader();
                loader.setLibraryPath( 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.138.2/examples/jsm/libs/rhino3dm/' );
                loader.parse( contents, function( object ) {
                    for (let i = 0; i < object.children.length; i++) {
                        if(object.children[i].userData.attributes.layerIndex == 1) {
                            cores.push(object.children[i].geometry);
                        }
                        else if(object.children[i].userData.attributes.layerIndex == 2) {
                            outline = object.children[i].geometry;
                        }   
                    }
                } );
            });
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer( this.files[0] );
        })
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are the two "console.log(this.loading)" fired with a noticiable delay? Try v-show intead of v-if.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer! Yes, the second "console.log" is executed by a button. 
Unfortunately, v-show produces the same result

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the scope of "this" is within the function block, meaning that this is no longer a reference to the Vue instance.

Using an arrow function which has no lexical scope and changing the last line to `reader.readAsArrayBuffer( fileInput.files[0] );` did the job.